# how do you set custom colors in ggplot heatmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1372698000, 1291129200, 1291388400, 
1298646000, 1386007200, 1295017200, 1382104800, 1385240400, 1265986800, 
1364835600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Logons = c("  973,675", 
"  710,782", "  734,635", "  812,793", "1,126,432", "  916,832", 
"1,011,911", "1,974,513", "  674,884", "1,278,295"), Month = structure(c(7L, 
11L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
    Max = c(973675L, 710782L, 734635L, 812793L, 1126432L, 916832L, 
    1011911L, 1974513L, 674884L, 1278295L), Year = c("2013", 
    "2010", "2010", "2011", "2013", "2011", "2013", "2013", "2010", 
    "2013")), .Names = c("Date", "Logons", "Month", "Max", "Year"
), row.names = c(453L, 2564L, 2636L, 3343L, 3435L, 4545L, 5275L, 
5786L, 7382L, 8077L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to create a heatmap where Year will be in y-axix and Month will be in x-axis.

I am doing this:

```
 ggplot(y ,aes(Month, Year, fill=Logons, label=paste(paste(weekdays(Date), format(Date,"%H:%M"), sep="\n"), "\n",Logons))) + geom_tile() + theme_bw() + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 1)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=45, hjust=1)) +  geom_text(size=3)+ scale_colour_manual(breaks = c(200000, 400000, 800000, 1000000, 1300000, 1500000), labels = c("0 month", "1 month", "3 months","6 months", "9 months", "12 months"),values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73","#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))
```

Not working. I get bunch of items on my legend, I only need 6 items and 6 color codes in my heatmap. Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem in your data is that `Logons` are treated as factor and not as numeric because there are commas inside numbers. So you have to convert them to numeric.

```
y$Logons<-as.numeric(gsub(",","",y$Logons))
```

As you have used `fill=` for `geom_tile()` then you have to use `scale_fill_...` to change fill values. In this case use `scale_fill_gradientn()` to format your fill values.

```
ggplot(y ,aes(Month, Year, fill=Logons, 
  label=paste(paste(weekdays(Date), format(Date,"%H:%M"), sep="\n"), "\n",Logons))) + 
  geom_tile() + theme_bw() + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=45, hjust=1)) +  
  geom_text(size=3)+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(200000,  1500000),
                       breaks = c(200000, 400000, 800000, 1000000, 1300000, 1500000), 
     labels = c("0 month", "1 month", "3 months","6 months", "9 months", "12 months"),
     colours = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73","#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))
```

Also I think you should remove `guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 1))` line from your code because fill colors change as gradient but now you get discrete values in legend that won't exactly match colors in plot.